# c# call multiple webservices at same time

Tags: multithreading, web-services, c#-4.0

Here is the deal, i have a website that is required to search from multiple webservices, then join all the results returned from webservices and display them mixed. I've done the code for search a single place at one

```
WsPesquisa pesq = new WsPesquisa();
IEnumerable<Objecto> Resultados = pesq.PesquisaObjecto("URL TO SEARCH", "TEXT TO SEARCH");
```

now i need to use threads to search in multiple places at once but having doubts how to do so.

Can someone please provide a thread sample to call multiple times the code i've used above and then join the results from all threads in a single List of Objectos?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a standard LINQ query, and use [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx) to parallelise it.

Assuming you have your query stored in `query`, a  list of the websites you want to search stored in variable called `sites`, and you have a method `SearchSite(string query, string site)` that runs the search against a single site, the following should do the trick:

```
var searchResults = from site in sites.AsParallel()
                    select SearchSite(query, site);

var resultList = new List<object>();
foreach (var searchResult in searchResults)
{
    // process result
    resultList.Add(searchResult);
}
```

This assumes the search query is the same for each site, so:

- `AsParallel()` indicates that you want your LINQ query to be run in parallel
- `select SearchSite(query, site)` - takes your query and runs the `SearchSite` method on it
- PLINQ takes care of waiting for all the results to come in, so you can just process them in a regular for loop